# org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.jmx.JmxUtil.registerJmx Jmx registration failed

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, permissions, securitymanager

I want to deploy deploy spring-boot application to external tomcat **with security manager enabled**. The Jndi is configured in tomcat with the name **jdbc/abc** .The tomcat asks for some permissions when I deploy, which I grant in the catalina.policy of the tomcat. I am presently getting some access denied message as shown below.

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.jmx.JmxUtil.registerJmx Jmx registration failed.
    java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanPermission" "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection#-[tomcat.jdbc:class=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource,connections=PooledConnection[0],name="jdbc/abc",type=ConnectionPool]" "registerMBean")
```

I then granted permission as

```
permission javax.management.MBeanPermission "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection#-[tomcat.jdbc:class=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource,connections=PooledConnection[0],name=jdbc/abc ,type=ConnectionPool]", "registerMBean";
```

then again the message repeats in the server output, I am not sure whether I granted this permission in the right way?
Can anyone suggest me where I am doing wrong?

The server configuration for connection pool is as shown below:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/abc"
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                  
                  url="url to the database"
                  username="MyName"
                  password="123" 
                  />
```

Comment: Any comments will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably be considered a bug in the [Tomcat JDBC](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) library: a `DataSource` provided by the container should use `AccessController.doPriviledged` to perform JMX operations. It also should provide a set of permissions to regulate access from application code to the `DataSource`. However since the `SecurityManager` will probably be deprecated (cf. [JEP 411](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/411)) I doubt that this bug will ever be resolved.

Since Tomcat JDBC registers lots of JMX beans, I would give to all the `org.tomcat.jdbc` classes permission to register any MBean in the `tomcat.jdbc` domain:

```
permission javax.management.MBeanPermission "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.*#-[tomcat.jdbc:*]", "registerMBean";
```

The `MBeanPermission` is granted using the:

```
permission javax.management.MBeanPermission "class name#member[object name]", "action"
```

(cf. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.management/javax/management/MBeanPermission.html)), where:

- *class name* is the class performing the call. In your case all Tomcat JDBC classes,
- *member* is the JMX attribute you want to access, doesn't apply for the `registerMBean` action,
- *object name* is an `ObjectName` pattern (cf. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.management/javax/management/ObjectName.html)): in your case all names in the `tomcat.jdbc` domain,
- *action* is the action to be performed: in your case Tomcat JDBC wants to register an MBean with the server.

You can also try more restrictive `ObjectName`s, e.g. `tomcat.jdbc:name=jdbc/abc,*` to restrict the permission to one datasource only.

**Remark:** If you don't intend to use JMX to monitor your datasource performance you can also use `jmxEnabled="false"` (cf. [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Tomcat_JDBC_Enhanced_Attributes)) and all permission problems will go away.